# Form is submitting the Array instead of the wanted field in CakePHP

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am new to cake and I am trying to learn its philosophy. So I am trying to create a form "Movie" as follows and my database accepts movie_id, title, year, and description. When I run the code it tries to store the "array" as the year input. This is the error I get => `movie_id`, `title`, `year`, `description`) VALUES (NULL, 'Movie1', Array, 'some text')

THE VIEW:

```
   <?php echo $this->Form->create('Movie'); ?>
    <?php echo __('Add Movie'); ?>

     <?php
        echo $this->Form->hidden('movie_id');

        echo $this->Form->input('title');

         echo $this->Form->input('year', array(
            'type'=>'date',
            'dateFormat'=>'Y',
            'minYear'=>'1990',
            'maxYear'=>date('Y'),
        ));

        echo $this->Form->input('description');

        ?>

<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); 

?>
```

THE CONTROLLER:

```
public function add() {

if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    $this->Movie->create();

      if ($this->Movie->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The movie has been created'));
        $this->redirect (array('action'=>'index'));
      } 

      else {

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The movie could not be created. Please, try again.'));

      }
}
}
```

As I said I am new to cake so my apologies if this question sounds stupid, please give your solution. Thanks

Comment: What's the datatype of your `year` column in the database?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. its simply YEAR. Should I change it?

Comment: Either that, or you have to transfom the value before saving it, as complex datatype deconstruction (see [**`Model::deconstruct()`**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.6/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1274)) is only supported for `DATETIME`, `DATE`, `TIMESTAMP` and `TIME` (no time for a longer answer right now, sorry).

Comment: did u solve your problem ?

Comment: Yeas i changed the input type using an options array as the Years selection. This is not though the solution I wanted but it will help me proceed for now.