# CakePHP form submits the "array"

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create a form "Movie" as follows and my database accepts movie_id, title, year, and description. When I run the code it tries to store the "array" as the year input. This is the error I get => movie_id, title, year, description) VALUES (NULL, 'Movie1', Array, 'some text')

THE VIEW:

```
 <?php 
   echo $this->Form->create('Movie'); ?>
    <?php echo __('Add Movie'); ?>

      <?php
          echo $this->Form->hidden('movie_id');
          echo $this->Form->input('title');
          echo $this->Form->input('year', array(
             'type'=>'date',
             'dateFormat'=>'Y',
             'minYear'=>'1990',
             'maxYear'=>date('Y'),
         ));
          echo $this->Form->input('description');

        ?>

 <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); 

?>
```

THE CONTROLLER:

```
public function add() {

if ($this->request->is('post')) {

    $this->Movie->create();

      if ($this->Movie->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The movie has been created'));
        $this->redirect (array('action'=>'index'));
  } 

  else {

    $this->Session->setFlash(__('The movie could not be created. Please, try again.'));

  }
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form is submitting the Array instead of the wanted field in CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952233/form-is-submitting-the-array-instead-of-the-wanted-field-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is here:

```
     $this->Form->input('year', array(
         'type'=>'date',
         'dateFormat'=>'Y',
         'minYear'=>'1990',
         'maxYear'=>date('Y'),
     ));
```

Instead of it you should use

```
     $this->Form->input('Movie.year', array(
         'type'=>'text',
         'name' => 'data[Movie][year]',
     ));
```

If you don't want to use 'text' type input, then use 'select' with your options array. Here main concern is, `Movie.year` and overwrite the default CakePHP's naming procedure to `'name' => 'data[Movie][year]'`. Check **[here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions)**.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. It really helped. I am accepting the solution of options instead of text but is really awkward when you are going to deal with huge amount of data sitting your ass hardcoding everything.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing to do is to debug your $this->request->data.

I'm not sure myself, but I once have this problem. What happen is, when you define an input as a date, it will be behave as an array. 
It will become `$this->request->data['Movie']['year']['year'];`

You can modify the data by doing the following

```
$this->request->data['Movie']['year'] = $this->request->data['Movie']['year']['year'];
```

Comment: Firstly thank you for replying. Ok this is a really fair answer and  and i followed your instructions. the thing is that I dont get any errors when i run it however i get the=> else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__('The movie could not be created. Please, try again.'));
        } ..... response. Any further ideas?

Comment: Is the flash being set and the record created? If the record isn't being created then the save method is returning false

Comment: The best is to debug your data. There is reasons why the form is not saved. Might be problem with the data or another things

Comment: eventually i ve been playing with i for a while and i used it like this. $this->Movie->create();
        if ($this->Movie->save($this->request->data['Movie']['year'] = $this->request->data['Movie']['year'])) then it creates the record but only the year record it leaves the inputs title and description blank. In other words it requests only the year field.. Any suggestions?

Comment: because you're only saving the year data.. have you try debug($this->request->data) .. It will be helpfull if you edit your question and include the debug result.